# MSP430 and RFM22

Tags: c, spi, msp430, texas-instruments, radio-transmission

i need help!

i have a TI msp-exp430g2 launchpad and a RFM22B and i need them to communicate with each other and i have no idea how to. after along time i came up with the code below to send data to the RFM22. i have an oscilloscope connected to the ANT pin of the RFM22 and i can see only noise and no output!

can anyone tell me what im doing wrong (alot abusively) and maybe someone has an example codes or a project that can help.

```
#include <msp430.h>

/*
 * main.c
 *
//                    MSP430G2xx3
//                 -----------------
//             /|\|              XIN|-
//              | |                    |
//              --|RST          XOUT|-
//                |                 |
//                |             P1.2|-> Data Out (UCA0SIMO)
//                |                 |
//          LED <-|P1.0         P1.3|-> nSel
//                |                 |
//                |             P1.4|-> Serial Clock Out (UCA0CLK)
 *
 */

//unsigned int address;
//unsigned char data;

void init(void);
void initRFM(void);
void write(int address, char data);

void txRFM(void);

int main(void) {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer
    int t;
    for (t=0;t<150;t++){  // 150 ms now
    __delay_cycles(1000); // 1000 usec
    }
    init();
    initRFM();
    while(1){
        txRFM();
    }
    return 0;
}

void txRFM(void){
    unsigned char i;

            write(0x07, 0x01);        // To ready mode
            __delay_cycles(50);

            write(0x08, 0x03);        // FIFO reset
            write(0x08, 0x00);        // Clear FIFO

            write(0x34, 64);        // preamble = 64nibble
            write(0x3E, 17);        // packet length = 17bytes
            for (i=0; i<17; i++)
            {
                    write(0x7F, 0xAA);        // send payload to the FIFO
            }

            write(0x05, 0x04);        // enable packet sent interrupt


            write(0x07, 9);        // Start TX
}


void write(int address, char data){
    P1OUT &= ~BIT3; // start write
    address |= 0x80;
    UCA0TXBUF = address;
    while ( ! ( IFG2 & UCA0TXIFG ) ) ;
    UCA0TXBUF = data;
    __delay_cycles(20);
    P1OUT |= BIT3; // end write
}

void init(void) {
    P1DIR |= BIT3; // P1.3 nSEL for writing to RFM22
    P1OUT |= BIT3; // no write
    P1SEL |= BIT2 + BIT4; // P1.4 clock out, P1.2 data out (UCA0SIMO)
    P1SEL2 |= BIT2 + BIT4;

    UCA0CTL0 |= UCCKPL + UCMSB + UCMST + UCSYNC;  // UCCKPL- inactive high, UCMSB- MSB first, UCMST- Master mode, UCSYNC- sync mode
    UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2;                     // SMCLK
    UCA0BR0 |= 0x02;                          // /2
    UCA0BR1 = 0;                              //
    UCA0MCTL = 0;                             // No modulation
    UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                     // **Initialize USCI state machine**
    IE2 |= UCA0RXIE;                          // Enable USCI0 RX interrupt
}
void initRFM(void){
    //write(0x03, 0x00);        // Disable all interrupts
    write(0x07, 0x01);                // Set READY mode
    write(0x09, 0x7F);                // Cap = 12.5pF
    write(0x0A, 0x05);                // Clk output is 2MHz

    write(0x0B, 0xF4);                // GPIO0 is for RX data output
    write(0x0C, 0xEF);                // GPIO1 is TX/RX data CLK output
    write(0x0D, 0x00);                // GPIO2 for MCLK output
    write(0x0E, 0x00);                // GPIO port use default value

    write(0x0F, 0x70);                // NO ADC used
    write(0x10, 0x00);                // no ADC used
    write(0x12, 0x00);                // No temp sensor used
    write(0x13, 0x00);                // no temp sensor used

    write(0x70, 0x20);                // No manchester code, no data whiting, data rate < 30Kbps

    write(0x1C, 0x1D);                // IF filter bandwidth
    write(0x1D, 0x40);                // AFC Loop
    //write(0x1E, 0x0A);        // AFC timing

    write(0x20, 0xA1);                // clock recovery
    write(0x21, 0x20);                // clock recovery
    write(0x22, 0x4E);                // clock recovery
    write(0x23, 0xA5);                // clock recovery
    write(0x24, 0x00);                // clock recovery timing
    write(0x25, 0x0A);                // clock recovery timing

    //write(0x2A, 0x18);
    write(0x2C, 0x00);
    write(0x2D, 0x00);
    write(0x2E, 0x00);

    write(0x6E, 0x27);                // TX data rate 1
    write(0x6F, 0x52);                // TX data rate 0

    write(0x30, 0x8C);                // Data access control

    write(0x32, 0xFF);                // Header control

    write(0x33, 0x42);                // Header 3, 2, 1, 0 used for head length, fixed packet length, synchronize word length 3, 2,

    write(0x34, 64);                // 64 nibble = 32 byte preamble
    write(0x35, 0x20);                // 0x35 need to detect 20bit preamble
    write(0x36, 0x2D);                // synchronize word
    write(0x37, 0xD4);
    write(0x38, 0x00);
    write(0x39, 0x00);
    write(0x3A, 's');                // set tx header 3
    write(0x3B, 'o');                // set tx header 2
    write(0x3C, 'n');                // set tx header 1
    write(0x3D, 'g');                // set tx header 0
    write(0x3E, 17);                // set packet length to 17 bytes

    write(0x3F, 's');                // set rx header
    write(0x40, 'o');
    write(0x41, 'n');
    write(0x42, 'g');
    write(0x43, 0xFF);                // check all bits
    write(0x44, 0xFF);                // Check all bits
    write(0x45, 0xFF);                // check all bits
    write(0x46, 0xFF);                // Check all bits

    write(0x56, 0x01);

    write(0x6D, 0x07);                // Tx power to max

    write(0x79, 0x00);                // no frequency hopping
    write(0x7A, 0x00);                // no frequency hopping

    write(0x71, 0x22);                // GFSK, fd[8]=0, no invert for TX/RX data, FIFO mode, txclk-->gpio

    write(0x72, 0x48);                // Frequency deviation setting to 45K=72*625

    write(0x73, 0x00);                // No frequency offset
    write(0x74, 0x00);                // No frequency offset

    write(0x75, 0x53);                // frequency set to 434MHz
    write(0x76, 0x64);                // frequency set to 434MHz
    write(0x77, 0x00);                // frequency set to 434Mhz

    write(0x5A, 0x7F);
    write(0x59, 0x40);
    write(0x58, 0x80);

    write(0x6A, 0x0B);
    write(0x68, 0x04);
    write(0x1F, 0x03);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with your specific radio, but I have worked extensively with TI CCxxxx radios connected with various TI dev kits (launchpad included).

I would begin by ensuring that your `hardwareInit()` routine sets up the SPI peripheral correctly. When I was developing with TI radios, I would do the following:

```
// Setup CSn line.
P2DIR |= BIT7;
P2OUT |= BIT7;
P2SEL &= ~BIT7;
P2SEL2 &= ~BIT7;

// Setup the USCIB0 peripheral for SPI operation.
UCB0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;
UCB0CTL0 |= (UCMODE_0 | UCCKPH | UCMSB | UCMST | UCSYNC);
UCB0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2;
UCB0BR1 = 0;
UCB0BR0 = 2;

// Setup SCLK, MISO, and MOSI lines.
P1SEL |= BIT5 | BIT6 | BIT7;
P1SEL2 |= BIT5 | BIT6 | BIT7;

UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;
```

Then I would test a `write()` function to ensure that I was writing using the peripheral correctly:

```
void write(unsigned char address, const unsigned char *buffer, unsigned char count)
{
    register volatile unsigned char i; // Buffer iterator

    // Change MISO pin to SPI.
    P1SEL |= BIT6;
    P1SEL2 |= BIT6;

    P2DIR &= ~BIT7;
    // Look for CHIP_RDYn from radio.
    while (P1IN & BIT6);

    // Write the address/command byte.
    UCB0TXBUF = address;

    // Write data byte(s).
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        while (!(IFG2 & UCB0TXIFG));
        UCB0TXBUF = *(buffer+i);
    }

    // Wait for operation to complete.
    while(UCB0STAT & UCBUSY);
    P2OUT |= BIT7;

    // Change MISO pin to general purpose output (LED use if available).
    P1SEL &= ~BIT6;
    P1SEL2 &= ~BIT6;
}
```